How many parts are in the first movement of Tchaikovsky's Piano Concerto No. 1?
How many parts are in the first movement of Tchaikovsky's Piano Concerto No. 1?
Of course, I oul split it into parts by myself based on my own perception, but I am more interested in having a look at traditional break-down done by experts. I am sure there should be one out there, except I can' find it. Wikipedia only provides a break-up into movements, not going any deeper.

Is there reason to believe it doesn't follow a conventional concerto structure? If not, then looking up how concertos are structured should be straightforward.

@Aaron - I believe you are talking about how many movements are traditionally included in one concerto and how slow or fast each one of those movements must be, right? If yes, then this is not waht I am after. What I want to know is the structure of the very first movement of Tchaikovsky' concert.

No, I'm talking about the structure of the first movement. Concertos are similar to sonatas in that the first movement follow (or diverge from) a conventional structure.

The first movement has a three-part structure plus a short introduction.
The concerto's first movement follows the large-scale sonata-form structure typical of many concertos. Formally, there are three main parts: exposition, development, and recapitulation. There is also a short introductory section before the exposition.
Wikipedia gives a reasonably detailed analysis of the movement.
Western Michigan University has a general description of the classic concerto form.
